# RS485 communication on Raspberry Pi Zero without converter

Tags: pi-zero-w

Is it possible to communicate in RS485 with another device without using a converter module (like MAX485) directly from the UART GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi Zero?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No - this is not possible. A UART does not have the hardware required for implementation of RS-485. Read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) for details.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. So it need a converter, a [MAX1487CSA](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/609/MAX1487_MAX491-3126622.pdf) may be ok for this?

Comment: That will depend on your *requirements*... [this guide](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/whp/rs-485-transceiver-tutorial) may help you narrow down your choices. Also - please [read this.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)